# Error importing Spark version 2.12.10 in Scala project Intellij IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-2.0, scala-2.12

I am trying to run Scala Spark code in IntelliJ IDE.

I have created the following `build.sbt` file in my project root directory:

```scala
name := "SimpleProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.8",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.8"
)
```

The Scala version I am using is **2.12.10** and the Spark version I am using is **2.4.8**.

The build is failing with the error `object apache is not a member of package org`:

[image]

The object that I have created in the Scala file:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  }
}
```

I tried reloading the project in the sbt tab and the build seems to be successful:

[image]

Then I tried `sbt clean package`, still getting the same error:

`object apache is not a member of package org [error] import org.apache.spark.SparkContext`

I am stuck here for a while now. My assumption was Spark would automatically resolve if it is passed as a dependency in the build.sbt file. But, it doesn't seem to work.

Would appreciate it if someone could help me fix this to work with Scala Spark.

Comment: One strange thing is the `target` folder inside `src/main/scala`. Not sure if related but I would get rid of it.

Comment: See if dependencias are included in the External Libraries floder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear InteliJ Cache?

-> Select File | Invalidate Caches from the main menu